# Can I use Lagrange's Theorem for rings with ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I know we can use Lagrange's Theorem for groups, but can we also use them for rings? So, suppose we have $R$ as a ring and $I$ as an ideal. Then would it be true to say $R$ only has $|R|/|I|$ distinct cosets? What are the limitations?

Comment: At least for finite rings maybe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this works perfectly fine.  A ring is in particular a group with respect to the addition operation, and any ideal is in particular a subgroup.  So any general statement about groups and subgroups will also be true for rings and ideals.

(Note that it doesn't really make sense to say there are $|R|/|I|$ distinct cosets when these sets could be infinite, division of infinite cardinalities cannot always be uniquely defined.  But what is true always is that $|R|=|I|\cdot|R/I|$.  This doesn't have anything to do with rings in particular though; this is just the correct way to state Lagrange's theorem for infinite groups.)

Comment: What if $R$ and $I$ were finite rings such that $|I|$ divides $|R|$

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to ask.

Comment: @OP do you want $I$ and $R$ to have some relationship with one another? Or do you just want them to be some arbitrary finite rings where $|I|$ divides $|R|$?

Comment: @EricWofsey I was trying to ask, if $R$ and $I$ were finite, then $|R|/|I|$ will be the number of distinct cosets of $I$ in $R$?

Comment: @D_S If $I$ was an ideal of $R$, wouldn't $|I|$ divide $|R|$ if we use Lagrange's theorem?

Comment: Yes, if $R$ is a finite ring and $I$ is an ideal in $R$ then there are $|R|/|I|$ cosets of $I$ by Lagrange's theorem.